# Onclick, change hover image JQUERY

Tags: jquery, hover, state

I have a standard list where the user clicks the headings and scrolls down items in currently hidden DIVs using jQuery's slideToggle().

In the  tag my CSS file declares that:

`a.showBlind:hover {background:url('img/scroll.png') right center no-repeat;}`

But once it's click I want that hover image to be different (i.e. an X icon to close the blind).  How can I set this using the jQuery?

I can find out the state of my DIV no problem. Currently my Jquery looks like this (unfinished):

```
$(".showBlind").click(function () {
            var group = $(this).attr("rel");
            $(".group"+group).slideToggle("slow",function () {
                var state = $(".group"+group).css("display");
            });
            switch (state)
            {   case "none":

                    break;
                case "block":

                    break;
            }
        });
```

in the `switch(state)` I want to modify the CSS for the a:hover.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You want to change image shown on hover after click and return old hover click after second click, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct and you need to change only hover image, you can do something like below.

Create css like this:

```
a.showBlind:hover {background:url('img/scroll.png') right center no-repeat;}
a.showBlind.closeIcon:hover {background:url('img/close.png') right center no-repeat;}
```

and than in your code

```
$(".showBlind").click(function () {
            var group = $(this).attr("rel");
            $(".group"+group).slideToggle("slow",function () {
                var state = $(".group"+group).css("display");
            });
            switch (state)
            {   case "none":
                    $(this).removeClass('closeIcon');
                    break;
                case "block":
                    $(this).addClass('closeIcon');    
                    break;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Aah nice idea.  Thank you, that makes alot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).css('background-image', 'path/to/image.jpg');
```

Remember that your path will now be relative to your HTML document, and not the CSS file.

Edit: jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YZFMf/

(Your switch statement was outside the slidetoggle function, meaning 'state' wasn't scoped properly...)

Comment: jquery has no :hover selector

Comment: also, how can I reference that with `$(this)` ?

Comment: yes I see what you mean, but now $(this) is referencing the wrong thing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YZFMf/1/ - define the (clicked) link as a variable, and then reference that.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, add another entry like this:

```
a.showBlind.hover:hover {background:url('img/X.png') right center no-repeat;}
```

And in your JavaScript add the class "hover" to the the element in question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you MassivePenguin and FAngel, I have resolved it now with both of your help!

My code reads as follows:

```
$(".showBlind").click(function () {
            var group = $(this).attr("rel");
            var myARef = $(this);
            $(".group"+group).slideToggle("slow",function () {
                var state = $(".group"+group).css("display");
                switch (state)
                {   case "none":
                        myARef.removeClass('closeIcon');
                        break;
                    case "block":
                        myARef.addClass('closeIcon');    
                        break;
                }
            });

        });
```

With the CSS that FAngel suggested:

```
a.showBlind             {width: 100%; display: block;}
a.showBlind:hover       {background: url('/img/scroll.png') right center no-repeat;}
a.showBlind.closeIcon:hover {background: url('/img/close.png') right center no-repeat;}
```

Thank you!